# Webkit-transform + Webkit-filter results in invisible div

Tags: html, css, webkit, transform

I'm running into a weird problem that makes a div invisible.
My goal is to create a shadow for a 3D object, in perspective.

Because a shadow is blurry, I am using `-webkit-filter: blur(8px);`, but when I try to add perspective with `-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg);`, and the amount of degrees is more than 45, the div just disappears.

My Chrome version is 27.0.1453.47 Beta

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PnCvX/) to reproduce the problem for yourself. (Chrome only.)

I hope you guys know more about this problem:).

Comment: Nope, works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/PnCvX/1/

Comment: That's pretty weird. Your fiddle renders nothing on my computer. I'm at Chrome Version 27.0.1453.47 beta-m. What version do you use?

Comment: Oops, should have mentioned, mine is Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: It's pretty weird. Friends of me don't get this problem either. They're on versions 25 to 26.

Comment: I guess it's because you're on a new beta version which isn't fully 'finished' yet.. maybe you could file a bug report or something

Comment: Well. There isn't really an answer to this question. It really seems to be version-specific. 27.0.1453, it is. It works on the Chrome Canari version.